# postgresql Row Level Security in .Net core

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core

I am getting the 42704: unrecognized configuration parameter rls.TenantId.
I created the row-level security policy in postgressql

```
CREATE POLICY tenant_isolation_policy
    ON public."Tenant"
    AS PERMISSIVE
    FOR ALL
    TO public
    USING ("TenantId" = current_setting('rls.TenantId')::uuid);
```

.Net core code

```
using (var command = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, connection))
{
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("TenantId", tenantId);
  command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such configuration parameter.

There are no "variables" in PostgreSQL. If you want to abuse a "placeholder parameter" to store a value, make sure that you have set it first (which causes it to exist).

Alternatively, use `current_setting(rls.TenantId', TRUE)`.

Note that the user can change the setting with the `SET` command if he or she finds a way to issue SQL statements, thereby subverting your row level security concept.